# How to get SearchBoxEx instance to modify its properties?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I need to modify the SearchResultPageURL property in a Search Box web part in an existing Enterprise Search Center. Apparently the Search Box is modeled in the SearchBoxEx class. So far, I couldn't figure out how to obtain the SearchBoxEx instance and I find it really hard to find any information on this subject.

How do I get the SearchBoxEx instance in C#?

Comment: Do you have to make the change through code?  You could edit the SearchBoxEx web part properties/Site Collection Search Settings instead.

Comment: Try this [thread][1]. I am sure it will give you good pointers.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931979/replace-default-search-box-in-sharepoint-2010-with-custom-one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself, a simple cast of the searchbox webpart is sufficient, like so:

```
//get the web part:
SPLimitedWebPartManager webPartManager = file.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared);
SPLimitedWebPartCollection webParts = webPartManager.WebParts;
var searchBoxWebPart = (from System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart webPart in webParts
                        where (webPart.Title.Equals("Search Box"))
                        select webPart).First();

//cast:
SearchBoxEx searchBox = (SearchBoxEx)searchBoxWebPart;
```